# Build multiple cpp files using cmake each with main function

Tags: c++, cmake

I have these files from github https://github.com/anthonywilliams/ccia_code_samples/tree/main/listings and I want to compile them all with debug symbols and debug them in VS. Each file also has it's own main so I have to generate a project for each one (but I've just read that you're not supposed to have more than 1 project per cmakelists). I'm trying to use cmake for the first time and getting a bit stuck

cmakelists.txt:

```
cmakelists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.22.1")


set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14")


project(ccia_listings)

file(GLOB source_files "src/*.cpp")

# Loop through each source file
foreach(source_file IN LISTS source_files)
    # Get the name of the file without the extension (e.g. 'a' from src/a.cpp'
    get_filename_component(target_name ${source_file} NAME_WE)
    
    # Create an executable with the above name, building the above source
    add_executable("${target_name}" "${source_file}")
endforeach()
```

The error I'm getting in cmake gui:

```
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

[image: my project structure]

Maybe the best bet is to forgo debugging in VS and instead of cmake use a python or bash script to just build and compile then dbug in gdb?

EDIT

I've got rid of the quotation marks around VERSION 3.22.1 and now I'm getting this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_executable):
  add_executable cannot create target "listing_c" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable created
  in source directory
```

Also tried doing `cmake_path(GET ${source_file} FILENAME target_name)`  but getting this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_executable):
  The target name "" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features,
  such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior.
```

EDIT Part2:

Ok it's because the files at the end of that listings folder have weird names e.g. listing_c.1.cpp

not sure how to deal with that but for now I'll just put them in a separate folder and ignore them

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. Adapt your CMakeLists.txt by adding `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)` as first line and it should go away. The version number does **not** need to be quoted.

Comment: "Each file also has it's own main so I have to generate a project for each one" - no, why? `add_executable` for each of the files, like it is written in your current cmakelists will work just fine.

Comment: I thought each VS project can only have 1 main?

Comment: No, you can generate as many executables in one solution as you want. Your might need to use `Set as startup project` context menu entry in the solution Explorer to select the executable for debugging and running.

Comment: You may try to use the `NAME_WLE` option for `get_filename_component`. This removes the path and the last extension :)

Comment: @Monty CMake will create one ***solution*** per cmake project command, but one VS project (=*.vcxproj file) per executable or library created in the cmake project. Those VS projects can become part of the toplevel VS solution and you can have an arbitraty (or at least very large) number of VS projects for executables having one main function each without getting into trouble. Note though that automatically generating executables based on file names makes it hard, if not impossible combine multiple sources into one executable or apply custom options.

Comment: That being said: If you want automatic project creations with the possibility to make the project more complex, I'd organize the sources as one exe per directory and list the subdirectories (preferrably by hardcoding them to the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`, but possibly using `file(GLOB ... LIST_DIRECTORIES true ...)`) and check for a `CMakeLists.txt` and adding them via `add_subdirectory` or by automatically generating a target depending on the check results. This allows you to include executables requiring more complex cmake logic while still allowing you to keep the cmake logic to a minimum.